# Clear selected value from select element after every change

Tags: angular

I have drop down and text field. The selected value from drop down displayed in text field. Now I want to clear the selected value i.e; display empty on drop down but for the first time it clearing and for rest it not working.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-5rxf6d)

I just want to show empty space on dropdown for every selection

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your code work by forcing change detection before resetting the bound value. This probably ensures that the change made in the `select` element is processed before we then set it to an empty value. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-lsdn3a).

```
logNoteSelectionChange(obj) {
  this.Otherlogs = obj;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.selectedLog = '';
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could remove the `[(ngModel)]` data binding on the `select` element:

```
<select #select ngModel (ngModelChange)="logNoteSelectionChange(select, $event)">
  <option *ngFor="let log of logCol">
    {{log.logMessage}}
  </option>
</select>
```

and reset the selected value in the `(ngModelChange)` event handler:

```
logNoteSelectionChange(select: HTMLSelectElement, obj: string) {
  this.Otherlogs = obj;
  select.value = "";
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-k74dsy) for a demo.

Comment: do you have any idea about why initially it working as expected and later failing  on clear ngModel bind value ?

Comment: I added an alternative solution that may give an idea of what is going on. I am not 100% sure, however.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correct and rely on previous question it is more clearer resolution

```
`<select #select class="form-group"
   (change)="logNoteSelectionChange(select,select.value)">
     <option *ngFor="let log of logCol">
        {{log.logMessage}}
     </option>
 </select>
```

`

here is a [link](https://angular-5-example-du5spz.stackblitz.io) to stackblitz

Comment: no, if you read my title you could understand my context. okay any way your suggestion not work. can you check the demo, it might help for better understanding.

Comment: What value , value of what ngModel, can you please explain what exactly you need, i checked demo, i can't get what do you want to achive @k11k2

Comment: You want to delete value from you select ngModel?

Comment: In demo for every selection I'm clearing the `selectedLog` which is bind to `ngModel` . for first time it clearing and showing empty and for the next it clearing but not reflecting to it.